# Access ngModel `$name` in custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

For my directive, I have the following which gets me most of where I need to go, my problem is that `ngModelCtrl` has an undefined property `$name` when executing the `.toggleFlyout()` function.  My intention is for it to be given a name so that the directive manages a named model set in the `ng-model` directive and propagates changes to that named model upwards to `scope.$parent`:

***Edit***: Plunkr of the attempt here: http://plnkr.co/edit/uD21fH62GLA5THs8ZuPj

`<button data-ng-model="flyoutIsToggled" data-flyout-toggle>Toggle Flyout</button>`

```
  .directive('flyoutToggle', function () {
    return {
      require: '^ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        var ngModelCtrl = ctrl;
        scope.toggleFlyout = function () {
          ngModelCtrl.$modelValue = !ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
          scope.$parent[ngModelCtrl.$name] = !ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
        }
        //ui->model
        element.bind('click', function (e) {
          scope.toggleFlyout();
        });
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: I'd rather have it be automatic.  Is there no access to the `flyoutIsToggled` model name created at `data-ng-model="flyoutIsToggled"`?

Comment: ^ Response to a retracted comment

Comment: What do you mean by ng-model on a button?

Comment: `$name` would normally be a form control name, what are you expecting it to be? Seems like you are trying to use `ng-model` just to have an isolated scope. Really not clear what the gaol is here

Comment: The opposite, I'm looking to propagate the model's change to a named /parameterized model in the parent scope.

Comment: As far as more detail, I posed this Plunkr of it: http://plnkr.co/edit/uD21fH62GLA5THs8ZuPj

Comment: And thanks @charlietfl, didn't realize $name was intended for forms

Comment: have looked at plunker...just not making sense.

Comment: I think this is an x/y problem. What is your real goal?

Comment: The goal is for the directive to be portable and agnostic of where it's located, simply creating a clickable element that adds a model of any name to parent scope (and toggles it).  In order to prevent model name collision, I wanted it to accept a parameter for model name.

Comment: can do what you want simply using `scope[attrs.attributeName]='someVal'`without all the complexity  http://plnkr.co/edit/7IpGgGUlNqjsGKTcqhlk?p=preview

Comment: Awesome, I just arrived at the same as well.  Copy it to an answer so I can mark it correct.

Comment: also note the use of `ng-click` so you don't have to use `$apply` with an external event handler

Comment: yeah, not a fan of that part just because I'm intending for it to have minimal number of required setup elements, but to each his own